# Pyqt5 - input text from one py file and show in another py file using textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a py file without any gui that randomise numbers every 2 seconds

I want that those number will be shown in a textbox in other .py file like this:
1
2
3
4

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Just import the random number generator script into your GUI script and update the GUI when new numbers are generated.

Comment: I dont want to upfate the gui every time. I just need tk find a way directing the numbers to the text box

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two files:

```
- generator.py
- gui.py
```

Say that `generator.py` contains the following function:

```
def returnName(name):
    return name
```

If we wanted to use that exact function in `gui.py` then all we would have to do is import the `returnName` function in `gui.py`:

```
from generator import returnName
```

Now you can use `returnName` in `gui.py`, even though it was originally defined in `generator.py`. The same principle applies to your random number generator function.

Comment: this is my random py: